# Reputation shorthand should be rounded down

Tags: feature-request, reputation

At this moment when reputation is shortened to say 10.1k this is because it is rounded up (10,050 becomes 10.1k). Flooring the result is in my opinion more fair because the users hasn't actually earned the 10,100 reputation points.

So `10.065` should be `10.0k`.

Comment: Meta.SE dupe: [Show shortened reputation in rounded down form](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/215404)

Answer (score 10):

Please don't. That's not how rounding works, generally.

I wouldn't want my (fictional) `9.999` rep to be displayed as `9k`. I feel that would be *more* inaccurate than `10k` when I'm short 1 rep.